# How to fix type 'Null' is not a 'bool' in boolean expression

Tags: flutter

I tried this code but the tenary operator is not working as it should as I am getting error and if put  String bgImage = (data['isDayTime']==null)? 'day.png' : 'night.png'; then I am only getting day.png
I am getting this error

The following TypeErrorImpl was thrown building Home(dirty, dependencies: [_ModalScopeStatus], state: _HomeState#1a387):
type 'Null' is not a 'bool' in boolean expression

Here is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  Map data = {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    data=data.isNotEmpty ? data : ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings?.arguments as Map;
    print(data);

    String bgImage = data['isDayTime']? 'day.png' : 'night.png';

    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/$bgImage'),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              )
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,120.0,0,0),
              child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    FlatButton.icon(
                      onPressed: () async {
                       dynamic result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/location');
                       setState(() {
                         data ={
                           'time': result['time'],
                           'location': result['location'],
                           'isDaytime': result['isDaytime'],
                           'flag': result['flag'],
                         };
                       });
              },
                      icon: Icon(
                          Icons.edit_location,
                          color: Colors.grey[300],
                      ),
                      label: Text(
                          'Edit Location',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.grey[300],

                      ),
                      ),
                    ),

                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                         data['location'],
                         style: TextStyle(
                           fontSize: 28.0,
                           letterSpacing: 2.0
                         )
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    Text(
                      data['time'],
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 66.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include the `argument` that you are passing?

Comment: bool? isDaytime;

Comment: Are you sure that the data will never be empty?

Comment: Like if it's empty, you're setting it via the argument coming from previous screen

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition from `data['isDayTime']?` to `data['isDayTime']!=null && data['isDayTime']==true?`.

Comment: Yes maybe explicitly adding `== true` should work

Comment: Checking both `data['isDayTime'] != null` and `data['isDayTime'] == true` is unnecessary since the second condition already implies the first.  It could be just `data['isDayTime'] == true`.  However, comparisons against `true` or `false` are usually a code smell; the intent would be clearer as `data['isDayTime'] ?? false`.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is here you are passing `bool? isDaytime` and this is nullable means it can be null. But
using `String bgImage = data['isDayTime']? 'day.png' : 'night.png';` means here `data['isDayTime']` either will be true or false. That's why you need to make sure you are not getting null value. Also, another null value can occur from modal route arguments.

1stly check if `data['isDayTime']` is null or not, then check it. You can follow @Monik's answer.

Answer (score 0):

change the condition to `String bgImage =data['isDayTime']!=null && data['isDayTime']==true? 'day.png' : 'night.png';`